# 'Error compiling Cython file error' from one day to another

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cython, spyder

I use a lot of special characters from Hun language, and there were no problems previously. Now they all give errors when running the whole script (F9). It still runs perfect when running locally (select + F5).

```
Fúú='bar'
```

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\my name\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_21a3824690cdb52a9fe6a3fa1c63ee73.pyx:1:1: Unrecognized character
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-dcfab52d0ff4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/elo/mindennap/untitled0.pyx', wdir='E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/elo/mindennap')

  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 703, in runfile
    ipython_shell.run_cell_magic('cython', '', f.read())

  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2131, in run_cell_magic
    result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)

  File "<decorator-gen-130>", line 2, in cython

  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)

  File "E:\Download\PROGIK\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py", line 321, in cython
    assert len(extensions) == 1

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

If I change to e.g.

```
Fuu='bar'
```

it works great. Why the sudden change of heart?

EDIT:
Have been messing around with FFMPEG and LIBAV yesterday, because wanted to download and convert Youtube videos to mp3. But I'm pretty sure I ran scripts with these characters succesfully after it.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Cython doesn't support unicode characters in variable names. It's an issue with their compatibility with Python 3 syntax so you might want to [report it was a bug](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues)

Comment: Is the issue partly that you've changed your file from a .py (Python) to a .pyx (Cython), and so are hitting Cython restrictions where you weren't before?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Python 3

Comment: @DavidW I had these characters in both .py and .pyx files before, not working for both of them at the moment. Is it possible I changed the compiler?

Comment: I don't believe unicode variable names has ever worked with Cython. It's possible that Spyder F9 was previously running it as a Python script rather than compiling it with Cython (assuming you aren't using Cython specific features).

Comment: @DavidW is there a way to compile with something else so these characters would work?

Comment: That you would want to be able to use (as input/output) those characters seem reasonable, but why do you want to use them to represent variables name? I am really curious as to the reason that [a-zA-Z0-9] would not be enough!

Comment: @Adonis Well, looks like that's the easiest solution. It's just much easier to use variable names in my own language and work with them, but have to compromise I guess, no big problem.